# Открытие окна на весь экран QML QT

Tags: windows, qt, qml

Имеется родительское окно, в которой есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должно открываться новое окно на весь экран, как при нажатии на кнопку maximized, новое окно выглядит так:

```
Window {
  id: window
  flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
       Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
       Qt.Window
  x: 0
  y: 0
  width: Screen.width
  height: Screen.height
  visible: true
}
```

Но значение Screen.height не учитывает высоту панели задач, то есть по идее высота должна быть Screen.height - (высота панели задач), заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте эти свойства использовать [desktopAvailableHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#desktopAvailableHeight-attached-prop) и [desktopAvailableWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html#desktopAvailableWidth-attached-prop). Не уверен насчет `windows`, в `ubuntu` работает.

Comment: спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
Window {
   width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
   height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
}
```

Comment: А теперь вот вопрос. Если на компе 2 монитора - как развернуться только в одном?

Answer (score 0):

```
Window {
   visibility: Window.FullScreen//так будет правильнее 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]